# Find the lowest value and its index until certain row within group

Tags: r, dataframe

I have R data.frame.
I want to find the lowest value until certain row and index of certain row

Here is the example.
This dataframe consist of subject, visit, value

```
subject = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)    
visit = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5)
value = c(100,97,120, 84, 60, 150, 150, 160, 100, 70, 40,120)    
a = data.frame(subject, visit, value)
```

[image]

I want find the minimum value until certain row and visit (index) of row having minimum value.

This is result I want to create

```
subject = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)    
visit = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5)
value = c(100,97,120, 84, 60, 150, 150, 160, 100, 70, 40,120)    
min = c(100, 97, 97, 84, 60, 60, 60, 160, 100, 70, 40, 40)
visit_min = c(1,2,2,4,5,5,5,1,2,3,4,4)
a1 = data.frame(subject, visit, value, min, visit_min)
```

[image]

I could not have found any way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cummin` to get minimum value until that row and use `match` to get the index.

```
library(dplyr)
a %>%
  group_by(subject) %>%
  mutate(min = cummin(value), 
         visit_min = match(min, unique(value)))

#   subject visit value   min visit_min
#     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <int>
# 1       1     1   100   100         1
# 2       1     2    97    97         2
# 3       1     3   120    97         2
# 4       1     4    84    84         4
# 5       1     5    60    60         5
# 6       1     6   150    60         5
# 7       1     7   150    60         5
# 8       2     1   160   160         1
# 9       2     2   100   100         2
#10       2     3    70    70         3
#11       2     4    40    40         4
#12       2     5   120    40         4
```

Comment: It works. I appreciate your help.